# C# Localization best practice for using same resource for multiple classes

Tags: c#, localization

I use a single Resource file to handle all my output message.  The message are coming from different classes.
So right now I do: Resource.ClassName_MethodName

```
//Output_Messages.Class_Method
string message = string.Format(Output_Messages.MyClass_MyMethod, Id/*parameter for value column*/);
```

I was wondering if there is a nice way to handle this, something that is similar to Namespace handling, that i can make Resource.class.methods.
The other options is to make resource class for each class outputs, but its overhead.

Comment: Would calling the resource simply `Namespace_ClassName_MethodName` do what you want?

Comment: No, you have only that options: multiple Resources.resx or some kind of notation for the name of resource items. Of course you can have a combination of them: one Resources.resx per namespace and MyClass_ResourceName notation for items.

Comment: `but its overhead.` why do you think so? Having a single large repository for everything is not?

Comment: @walther I gather several classes under some resources, if i make resource for each class, there will be too many resources.

Comment: @ilansch, what do you consider `too much`? Furthermore, why do you group resources by class? You should try to split them logically, not based on some class implementation. Your classes can change, you can refactor etc. Then you will try to find all corresponding resources and update them one by one? Hopefully not... You're coupling your logic too much.

Comment: Well, I gather my resource per process, not per class, each process contains several classes.